# Strange Matrix with \NiceMatrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, stix, nicematrix

I've got trouble with `\tikzpicture`: my goal is take only the sides of 15-gon for the first part of tex-code,... But I don't remember how to do it
.
And then the I'd like to have  `\begin{matrix*}...` at the center of two polygons, possibly improved with `\nicematrix`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2} \def\N{15}
\draw (0,0) circle(\R);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\N} 
{\coordinate (P-\i) at (\i*360/\N:\R);
\draw (P-\i) circle(5pt);}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\N-1}       \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
\foreach \k in {\j,...,\N} \draw (P-\i) -- (P-\k);} \end{tikzpicture}}
%\rotatebox{90}{%
\NiceMatrixOptions
{nullify-dots,code-for-first-col = \color{blue},code-for-first-col=\color{blue}}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
&\Ldots[line-style={solid,->},shorten=0pt]^{\text{Con le diagonali}} \\
&\mbox{Decapentagono}
\vspace{-2mm}\\&\Ldots[line-style={solid,<-},shorten=0pt]_{\text{Senza diagonali}}
\end{NiceMatrix}$
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2} \def\N{15}
\draw (0,0) circle(\R);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\N} 
{\coordinate (P-\i) at (\i*360/\N:\R);
\draw (P-\i) circle(5pt);}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\N-1}       \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
\foreach \k in {\j,...,\N} \draw (P-\i) -- (P-\k);}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, My codex is badly written.... I don't know write it well, how must I do? Thx, Best

Comment: Could the one who has modified my code tell me how to do it, please? Thank you

Comment: To add proper markup for code, select the code and hit Ctrl + K. I think you forgot to add  `\usepackage{mathtools}` to your example?

Comment: @Puck you can see what the editor changed by clicking on the "edited ... mins ago"

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I added `\usepackage{mathtools}`

Comment: @Marcus Müller. Several things are modified... Now the tex-code functions well. Thank to you others.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you want to do. You want to take the edges (not vertices) of the K15 on the LHS and copy that to the RHS, right? So you just delete `circle(5pt)` in the second K15.

Comment: @Simbol 1. On the left I would just like to create a decapentagon, for the central part I would like something like this:
An inscription (Decapentagon) in the center with a `\xrightarrow[]{With diagonals}` above and with a `\xleftarrow[Without diagonals]{}`. Is It possible with `nicematrix`?

Comment: I modified all the code. Now I think it is clearer than before what I'd like to do, isn't it? If so, I'd like that "Decapentagono" is aligned with the centers of polygons at sides. For 1st polygon I'd like to have only the sides and not the diagonals, too (of course left-polygon must be stay inscribed in circonference!). I need your help please. Thx in advanced, Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\def\R{2} \def\N{15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline ={(0,0)}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,\N} { \coordinate (P-\i) at (\i*360/\N+90/\N:\R); }
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\N-1} 
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
   {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}       
      \draw (P-\i) -- (P-\j) ;
   } 
\draw (P-\N) -- (P-1) ;
\fill (0,0) circle (0.5mm) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\tiny Con le diagonali \\[-1mm]
\rightarrowfill \\
Decapentagono \\
\leftarrowfill \\[-2mm]
\tiny Senza diagonali
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
\draw (0,0) circle(\R);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\N} { \coordinate (P-\i) at (\i*360/\N+90:\R); }
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{\N-1}       
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
   {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
      \foreach \k in {\j,...,\N} \draw (P-\i) -- (P-\k);
   } 
\fill (0,0) circle (0.5mm) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for this great solution. But I'd like that left-and-right-polygons are 90°-rotated. Furthermore I'd like to create the center of the two polygons. Is it possible? Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is solved.